# Trying to run a demo app but tomcat seems to be running but browser is throwing 404

Tags: java, spring-boot

Here is my POM:

https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.2.0.M5
         
    
    com.example
    demo
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    demo
    Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>`enter code here`spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

And this is my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        return args -> {

            System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

            String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
            Arrays.sort(beanNames);
            for (String beanName : beanNames) {
                System.out.println(beanName);
            }

        };
    }
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }

}
```

The output says that everything is up and running:

But browser gives me 404 - NOT found when i try to do http://localhost:9080/hello

Not sure whats going on

Application.properties file:

server.port=9080

[image]

Comment: Did you configure it in properties file for this port? I believe that by default the server starts on 8080 and not 9080

Comment: com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on LAPTOP-GQ31D0D4 with PID 12544
com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9080 (http)
.......
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9080 (http) with context path ''
com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 1.253 seconds (JVM running for 1.577)

Comment: I'd suspect that problem is that you don't provide request method for RequestMapping try providing it, or using GetMapping instead

Comment: Can you add your `application.properties` file to question?

Comment: Added application.properties file